# How to hide show for increase element

Tags: jquery

I want to make two part block, when I hover to title ( have id = 0 ) and the image with id = 0 will be show and so on, when I mouse out the img hide. And if default, the image with id 0 will be active. I tried these code bellow:

HTML

```
<div id="post_slider_img_id_0"><img class="img-1" src="#"></div>
<div id="post_slider_img_id_1"><img class="img-1"  src="#"></div>
<div id="post_slider_img_id_2"><img class="img-1"  src="#"></div>
<div id="post_slider_img_id_3"><img class="img-1"  src="#"></div>
<li id="post_slider_title_id_0"><a href="#">Title 01</a></li>
<li id="post_slider_title_id_1"><a href="#">Title 02</a></li>
<li id="post_slider_title_id_2"><a href="#">Title 03</a></li>
<li id="post_slider_title_id_3"><a href="#">Title 04</a></li>
```

JQUERY

```
var count = -1;
$("#post_slider_title_id_" + count++).mouseover(function() {
    $("#post_slider_img_id_" + count++).show();
});
```

Comment: Where is `post_slider_title_id_*` in your html?

Comment: ah sorry I've just edit my code, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it like this.

```
$("[id^=post_slider_title_id_]").mouseover(function() {
  $("#post_slider_img_id_0").hide();
  var id = '#post_slider_img_id_' + $(this).attr("id").replace('post_slider_title_id_','');
  $(id).show();
});

$("[id^=post_slider_title_id_]").mouseout(function() {
  var id = '#post_slider_img_id_' + $(this).attr("id").replace('post_slider_title_id_','');
  $(id).hide();
  $("#post_slider_img_id_0").show();
});
```

Also hide all except first on start.

Comment: Thank you, so how to make #post_slider_img_id_0 show as default, I have idea add Class active and css active display block but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are also hiding content on mouse leave?

Comment: Yes, I use this code :  `$("[id^=post_slider_title_id_]").mouseover(function() {
  var imgShow = '#post_slider_img_id_' + $(this).attr("id").replace('post_slider_title_id_','');
  $(imgShow).show();
 }); 
 $("[id^=post_slider_title_id_]").mouseout(function() {
  var imgHide = '#post_slider_img_id_' + $(this).attr("id").replace('post_slider_title_id_','');
  $(imgHide).hide();
  $("#post_slider_img_id_0").addClass("active");
 }); `

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that `count++` will be incremented twice. That's not what you want. If your markup is simple enough, you can actually simply use `.index()` to get the relative index of the title, and then use `.eq()` to find the image of the corresponding index. To avoid needing to declare unique IDs, you can attach a shared class to all the post slider titles, and another class to all the post slider images:

```js
$('.post_slider_title').mouseover(function() {
  const i = $(this).index();
  $('.post_slider_img').eq(i).show();
});
```

```css
.post_slider_img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post_slider_img"><img class="img-1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=1"></div>
<div class="post_slider_img"><img class="img-1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=2"></div>
<div class="post_slider_img"><img class="img-1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=3"></div>
<div class="post_slider_img"><img class="img-1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=4"></div>

<ul>
  <li class="post_slider_title"><a href="#">Title 01</a></li>
  <li class="post_slider_title"><a href="#">Title 02</a></li>
  <li class="post_slider_title"><a href="#">Title 03</a></li>
  <li class="post_slider_title"><a href="#">Title 04</a></li>
</ul>
```

If that is not an option, then you can simply store the index in a HTML5 `data-` attribute:

```js
$('.post_slider_title').mouseover(function() {
  const i = this.dataset.target;
  
  $('#post_slider_img_id_' + i).show();
});
```

```css
div[id^="post_slider_img_id_"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="post_slider_img_id_0"><img class="img-1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=1"></div>
<div id="post_slider_img_id_1"><img class="img-1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=2"></div>
<div id="post_slider_img_id_2"><img class="img-1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=3"></div>
<div id="post_slider_img_id_3"><img class="img-1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100?text=4"></div>

<ul>
  <li class="post_slider_title" data-target="0"><a href="#">Title 01</a></li>
  <li class="post_slider_title" data-target="1"><a href="#">Title 02</a></li>
  <li class="post_slider_title" data-target="2"><a href="#">Title 03</a></li>
  <li class="post_slider_title" data-target="3"><a href="#">Title 04</a></li>
</ul>
```